# Finite potential well; finding the energy "in a limit"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation

> I've come a across the following variant of the finite-potential-well-problem in quantum mechanics: The potential is given by $V(x)=0$ for $|x| \geq a/2$ and $V(x)=-V_0/a$ for $-a/2<x<a/2$ where $a,V_0>0$.The task is to find an eigenfunction and an eigenvalue for the Hamiltonian "in the limit $a \to 0$".

My problem is that I am not sure what "in the limit $a \to 0$" should mean in this context. My first idea was to use the energy formula for the finite well, plugging in $V_0/a$ and $a/2$ for the potential resp. the width of the box and then take the limit $a \to 0$. However, this does not give a meaningful result.

The energy formula I am working with is
$$K\tan(K\frac{a}{2})=S$$
where
$$K=\sqrt{\frac{2m(E+V_0/a)}{h^2}}$$
$$S=\sqrt{\frac{-2mE}{h^2}}$$
and $h$ is Planck's constant.

Maybe someone has an idea what "in the limit $a \to 0$" should mean here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given potential energy in the finite-potential-well-problem is
$$V(x)=\begin{cases}
  0, & |x| > \frac{a}{2} \\
  -\frac{V_0}{a}, & -\frac{a}{2} < x < \frac{a}{2}
\end{cases}$$

In the limit $a \to 0$ this potential is an infinitely narrow and deep peak.
Therefore it can most conveniently be written by using the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
Its size (height$\cdot$width) is $-\frac{V_0}{a} \cdot a = -V_0$, hence
$$V(x)=-V_0 \delta(x)$$

Then Schrödinger's time-independent equation becomes
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x) - V_0 \delta(x) \psi(x) = E \psi(x) \tag{1}$$

This differential equation can be solved with standard calculus methods.
Below I only sketch how to find the bound-state solution.
Finding the solutions for unbound states is left to you.

Inspired by the solution of the [finite-potential-well-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well),
we make the following ansatz for eigenfunction and eigenvalue
(with a still unknown $\alpha$).
$$\begin{align}
 \psi(x) &= A e^{-\alpha|x|} \tag{2a} \\
 E &= - \frac{\hbar^2\alpha^2}{2m} \tag{2b}
\end{align}$$

From (2a) and with the help of $|x|'' = 2\delta(x)$ (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059863/second-derivative-of-absolute-value-function-proportional-to-dirac-delta-functio))
we can calculate the second derivative of $\psi$
$\psi''(x) = \alpha^2 Ae^{-\alpha|x|} - 2\alpha A\delta(x) \tag{3}$

When plugging (2a), (2b) and (3) into Schrödinger's equation (1),
we see that most terms cancel out, and get a single solution for $\alpha$:
$$\alpha = \frac{mV_0}{\hbar^2} \tag{4}$$
and hence there is only one bound state.

Using this $\alpha$ in the ansatz (2) finally gives the solution
$$\begin{align}
 \psi(x) &= A e^{-mV_0|x|/\hbar^2} \\
 E &= -\frac{mV_0^2}{2\hbar^2}
\end{align} \tag{5}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can "mimic" the computation you outlined but I do not understnad what I am doing. (I am a math student.) So, what exactly is $\delta(x)$? I know some basics about distributions and - as far as I understand - $\delta(x)$ is an abuse of notation. So, what would be the correct notation for $\delta(x)$ or for the equation involving $\delta(x)$?

Comment: Well, $\delta(x)$ is not a function in the sense of rigorous mathematics.
I know, mathematicians call it a distribution.
But I never needed to learn distribution theory to understand and use it.
Looosely speaking, you can imagine $\delta(x)$ as a peaked "function"
which is $=0$ for all $x\neq 0$, and $=\infty$ for $x=0$,
in such a way that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x) dx = 1$.
I know mathematicians feel uncomfortable with this explanation,
but for physicists (including me) this is just enough to know.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, Thomas. I asked my question about the exact meaning of $\delta(x)$ on math stackexchange. The title of my question is "Schrödinger equation involving the Dirac-Delta". Maybe they know more... :-)

Comment: Link: [Schrödinger equation involving the Dirac-Delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265602/schr%c3%b6dinger-equation-involving-the-dirac-delta)